# Conditional validation depending on POST parameter Django

Tags: django, validation

I have a form that I am trying to have some "conditional" validation on, depending on the button the user clicks.

The fields should all be required if the user clicks "Submit", and **none** should be required if the user clicks "Draft".

My models specify that no fields are required, to accomdate the draft. Then I tried to override it to require the validation only when a certain button is clicked, but I can't figure out for the life of me how to do it.

I've simplified the code below.

The form:

```
class MOCForm(forms.ModelForm):
    facility = forms.CharField(required=False)

def fields_required(self, fields):
  """Used for conditionally marking fields as required."""
  for field in fields:
    if not self.cleaned_data.get(field, ''):
      msg = forms.ValidationError(" This field is required.")
      self.add_error(field, msg)

def clean(self):
  self.fields_required(['facility'])
  return self.cleaned_data
```

The view method:

```
def post(self, request):
if request.POST.get('_start') == '' or request.POST.get('_draft') == '':
    MOC_form = forms.MOCForm(request.POST, prefix="MOC_form", instance=MOC)
    if request.POST.get('_draft') == '' or MOC_form.is_valid():
      MOC_form.save()
      if request.POST.get('_start') == '':
        MOC.submitted_date = timezone.now()
      if request.POST.get('_draft') == '':
        MOC.status = C.moc_status_draft()
      if request.POST.get('_start') == '' or request.POST.get('_draft') == '':
        MOC.creator = request.user
      MOC.save()
      if request.POST.get('_start') == '' or request.POST.get('_draft') == '':
        # If there is an activation (i.e. it is part of the flow), redirect appropriately
        if request.activation:
          request.activation.process.MOC = MOC
          request.activation.done()
          return redirect(get_next_task_url(request, request.activation.process))
        # Otherwise, just reload the same page (likely the dashboard)
        else:
          return redirect(request.path)
    else:
      if request.POST.get('_start') == '' or request.POST.get('_draft') == '':
        context = {}
        return render(request, 'MOC/CreateMOC.html', context)
```

The problem is that even if I take out the `MOC_form.is_valid()` check **entirely**, it still gives me the same error: `The MOC could not be changed because the data didn't validate.`

I want to skip this validation entirely, but only if the POST parameters include the submitted '_draft' - but I don't have access to POST params inside of the clean method. How would I go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Better way to handle this Is to submit the draft using another form and the required form as another form instance setting the required to True or False as per requirement. Look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#required https://krzysztofzuraw.com/blog/2016/two-forms-one-view-django.html

Comment: Definitely not a simple way to handle it, but in practical terms that does make sense. Thanks for the advice - if I can't find another way, I'll go that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I don't have access to POST params inside of the clean method

You *do* have the access, because you pass the POST data as `data` attribute of `MOCForm.__init__`.

And so you can do it this way:

```py
class MOCForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # your class definition as above

    def clean(self):
        if '_draft' in self.data:
            # skip check
        else:
            # clean data
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but this project isn't even in use anymore, so I can't validate that this is correct - but if so, that would be a very simple and powerful (and in hindsight, obvious) way to do it, thanks!